# Removing carriage return characters from a file using python

Tags: python, carriage-return

```
import os
import sys

files = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
for file in files:
    if file[-4:] == ".png":
        os.rename(file, file.replace('\r', ''))
```

Am using the above code to remove \r from the file name, but some how when I execute I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renameImages.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.rename(f, f.replace('\r', ''))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What are you passing as an argument?

Comment: Are you saying that the FILE NAME has a '\r' character? I think that this is probably not the case...

Comment: Yes the filename has a '\r' character.

Comment: @LearnCode: that is a very unfriendly file name that will break many programs...

Comment: @drewk: The image is being generated by a script and somehow the '\r' character is creeping so I wanted to remove it. I understand what you say, will rectify the bug.

Comment: You should not use "`file`" as a variable name.  There is a builtin by the same name.  consider "filename"?  Unrelated to the issue you're having.

Comment: You should use the `endswith` method of strings to test if they end with a particular substring, like: `filename.endswith('.png')` That way you don't have to specify the substring length, which is error-prone.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't tell it the directory of the file, that was declared in `argv[1]`
try `os.rename(sys.argv[1]+"/file",sys.argv[1]+"/"+replace('\r'','')`
(or '\\' for Windows).

Comment: Your welcome! But I would really like to know how you got \r's in your filename. I didn't think that was possible o__o

Comment: almost any character is *possible* in a posix filename, except forward slash (`/`) and the null byte.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join(dirname, filename)` when building paths, as it automatically uses the correct path separator, ie. `'/'` for linux and `'\\'` for windows. You can also give it more than two paths, eg. `os.path.join(all, the, path, components)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.rstrip('\r') method to remove a set of characters from the right side of a string:

```
>>> s="this is your brain on drugs\r\n\r\n"
>>> s
'this is your brain on drugs\r\n\r\n'
>>> s=s.rstrip('\n\r ')
>>> s
'this is your brain on drugs'
```

You say in your post that the file name has a `\r` at the end of it; this would be very unusual. Are you sure that your file name has a `\r` at the end of the string or you are assuming it does because you used Python to print it? Remember that Python appends an automatic return to a string that you print.

**Edit**

OK: the file name really has a `\r` on the end. My first recommendation is to fix the script that is producing such unfriendly file names...

For this scipt, you need to either prepend the directory name on the front or CD into the relevant directory. Since [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520251/removing-carriage-return-characters-from-a-file-using-python/5520273#5520273) answer has the prepending, here is CD'ing:

```
try:
    os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
except OSError:
    print "can't change to ",sys.argv[1]
    sys.exit(1)

# proceed with the rest of your script...
```

Comment: the '\r' character in particular is not at the en but in between of the filename. It is of the format <filename>.^M.png, so to remove this am using the above script. Actually the image works fine in linux but windows doesn't recognise the file so I used the above script to remove the carriage return character